# How to index child on top of parent's brother's children

Tags: actionscript-3, z-index

I'm having troubled with indexing in Actionscript 3.0. Basically I have two objects that are spawned on the stage. One is dock and the other a ball object. How it works is that when a ball object is over the dock, a info window appears on the screen. The ball object has a wrapper called Container.

So the objects are: MainClass, Dock, Container, BallObject, InfoWindow.

So from back to front it's: MainClass > Dock > InfoWindow > Container > BallObject.
Dock and Container are added in the Main class, and infoWindow is added in the Dock class and BallObject from the Container class.

What I want to achieve is to have the InfoWindow on top of the BallObjects, without the Dock being in front of the Container or BallObjects.

Here is an image to help illustrate things out.
d = dock c = container B = ballobject I = infowindow[image]

The image on the left is what I want to achieve and the one right is what I have right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your hierarchy it is impossible, as the DisplayList is a tree as a whole, and is rendered depth first. So, put Container under Dock, and give it child index less than InfoPanel.

```
dock.addChild(container);
dock.addChild.infoPanel);
container.addChild(ball);
main.addChild(dock);
```

This approach will net you the requested goal. In case you need to add another layer, say between Container and InfoPanel, add another container between them, and add required stuff to that container.

Comment: Hi Vesper thanks for your answer but this solution is not applicable for me. I forgot to mention that I have multiple docks and multiple containers. If I add container to dock, I would have multiple containers connected to every dock. Also I simplified my work to ask the question but what is really happening is that docks have a dock manager and

Comment: This means you have to rethink your display list hierarchy. You cannot make it so that part of the objects of the same subtree were above and part below an object from another subtree. Perhaps you should employ a layered model where one layer contains all docks, the next layer has all containers, and the third layer contains info messages and other popup stuff.

Comment: Thanks Vesper, I'll do just that.